# Can I send a Whatsapp broadcast message from my Android app to selected contacts?

Tags: android, android-intent, whatsapp

I am building an Android app and have a broadcast list on Whatsapp. How can I send message to the Whatsapp broadcast list from my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now there is no API/method released by Whatsapp to support that.

You can either create a message Intent for Whatsapp and choose the contact to which you wish to send as shown in the following link: https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/28000012

Or you can send a pre specified message directly to a contact from your app, by implementing the below:

```
try {
    startActivity(new Intent(
        Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
        Uri.parse(
            String.format(
            "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=%s&text=%s",
            "+919999999999", getString(R.string.your_message)
            )
        )
    ));
} 
catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
        "Whatsapp is not installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```